Why Buddha considered as 9th incarnation of lord Vishnu
If Buddha was 9th incarnation of lord Vishnu according to most of the purans so Buddha denied the whole vedas if he was against the corrupted part of vedas so he can able denied that particular part but he denied whole vedas and form a new religion?

This question is similar to: Why is there a separate religion for Buddha, if Buddha is a Hindu god?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Abhinav Verma According to Shri Madhvacharya, the incarnations of Shri Vishnu (i.e. God) are perfect and complete. They experience no conflict and pain but only display human-like behavior to teach people how to execute and protect righteousness or to delude demonic souls so that they can think God is not God and go to eternal hell. Eternal hell is called Andhatamas (Andha = blinding and tamas = darkness)

@AbhinavVerma Demonic souls intrinsically prefer to hate the Supreme Lord Vishnu and they thrive in an environment that reinforces their perverse hatred and jealousy. Since hatred and jealousy can only be reinforced by tremendous pain and agony, these demonic souls thrive in a very painful environment and thus their intrinsic natures are in consonance with their surroundings. Since the Supreme Lord Vishnu is free from any defects and is an embodiment of perfect justice, He provides these demonic souls a means to reach their intrinsically preferred state, which is eternal hell (Andhatamas)

@AbhinavVerma Andhatamas, or eternal hell, is very different from the temporary hells. The pain in the latter hells is there to punish soul for their sins so that they can redeem themselves and go to their next births. Since (finite duration of sins = finite time for punishment) souls don't stay forever in these hells. Andhatamas, however, is not a place of punishment but a final destination. Although the pain experienced in Andhatamas is much greater than the pain in the temporary hells, Andhatamas is place filled with activity .... and extreme pain, hatred, and jealousy towards Lord Vishnu

@AbhinavVerma Lord Buddha is none another than the perfect Lord Vishnu, the giver of sad-gati. He propounded a false religion due to His judicious nature: He enabled demonic souls a means to reach their intrinsically preferred state of Andhatamas. This is the purpose of Buddhism. However, because the Supreme Lord Narayana is Sarva-sabdha-vaacha (i.e. all sounds are His names or refer to His activities, fame, and supremacy), Buddhist philosophy, when read in a particular way, extol the greatness of Shriman Narayana and therefore is equivalent to the adhyatmika interpretation of the Vedas.

@AbhinavVerma Whatever Shri Vishnu does is done with malice towards none. Just as He provides false religions to enable demonic souls to reach their intrinsically preferred state (eternal hell), He preaches the true religion to enable muktiyogas to reach their intrinsically preferred state of moksha. Moksha is a state of bliss where blissful souls thrive.

Buddha knew that even if he complains about corrupt part there will be no takers, rather  come out with a new religion.
